# How do I translate 'do well on your test' into Chinese?

Tags: politeness, phrase-request

How do I translate 'do well on your test' into Chinese?

My friend is taking a test tomorrow. Although he speaks English to me, I thought it would be nice to wish him success in chinese.

Is 祝你好运测试 correct (or adequate)?

Comment: It should be `祝你测试好运`. However the English word "test" could be 测试, 测验, or 考试 in Chinese and they're subtly different.

Answer (score 3):

I basically agree with what Itux just said. But I would prefer to say “祝你考试顺利” instead of “祝你测试顺利”.

In your context, “考试” would be the word you look for when you want to translate "test" or "exam". As for "quiz", it's usually “小测”. “测验” means test indeed but in a much more general way. People tend to just use “考试” when they talk something about school, especially in daily conversations.

Answer (score 1):

You could just say "祝(wish)你(you)好(good)运(luck)". "祝你好运" is usually used alone, neither "祝你好运测试"[incorrent usage] nor "祝你测试好运"[partially correct usage] is typical usage in Chinese.

I would suggest "祝你测试顺利", literally translated as "wish(祝) you(你) test(测试) smooth/successful(顺利)".

Answer (score -1):

根据语言环境， 我能想到两种翻译：

1. 命令句式：  把你的测试考（做）好
2. 祝福，类似于 good luck:   （祝）考试顺利 / （祝)你考试取得好的成绩